# Is there a way to completely reset an asp.net validator with callouts?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have a web form and I want the user to be able to reset the form without doing a full post back (I know that's the easiest way).

I'm using asp.net validators with callouts, nothing too fancy.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWarranty" MaxLength="50" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvWarrantyID" runat="server" Display="None"
    ControlToValidate="txtWarranty" ErrorMessage="Warranty ID is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceWarrantyID" HighlightCssClass="wpcf7-not-valid" TargetControlID="rfvWarrantyID"
    runat="server" />
```

When the user resets the form I want to clear all the fields and reset all the validators.  It works for the most part.

```
function ResetWarrantyForm() {
    document.forms[0].reset();
    ClearValidation();
}
function ClearValidation() {
    var validators = window.Page_Validators;
    for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
        validators[i].IsValid = true;
        window.ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validators[i]);
        try {
            var callOutId = validators[i].ValidatorCalloutBehavior._id;
            var callOut = window.$find(callOutId);
            if (callOut)
                callOut.hide();
        }
        catch (e) { }
        validators[i].IsValid = true;
        window.ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validators[i]);
    }
    if (typeof (window.Page_ValidationSummaries) != "undefined") { //hide the validation summaries  
        for (var sums = 0; sums < window.Page_ValidationSummaries.length; sums++) {
            var summary = window.Page_ValidationSummaries[sums];
            summary.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    $("input[type='text'], select").removeClass("wpcf7-not-valid").removeClass("comboboxNotValid");
}
```

The problem is that once a validation has been evaluated.  The input is set to validate on focus.  So when the form is reset, and a user clicks on the text box.  They are immediately told that their input is invalid, even though they haven't done anything yet.

On the first page load, the fields don't validate until the button click.  But after that first button click the fields validate on focus and on blur.

Is there a way to reset that behavior as if it's the first load again?

Comment: You got any solution for this ? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @RickJackson, I can't remember if I got it working exactly as I hoped, but I posted the function that I created to get as close as I could.  You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this javascript function

```
function ClearValidation() {
    //reset the form
    document.forms[0].reset();
    //get all the validators
    var validators = window.Page_Validators;
    for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
        validators[i].IsValid = true;
        window.ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validators[i]);
        //Clear out all the callouts and hide them
        try {
            var callOutId = validators[i].ValidatorCalloutBehavior._id;
            var callOut = window.$find(callOutId);
            if (callOut)
                callOut.hide();
        }
        catch (e) { }
        // I can't remember why I repeated this code, not sure if necessary
        validators[i].IsValid = true;
        window.ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validators[i]);
    }
    // hide the summary
    if (typeof (window.Page_ValidationSummaries) != "undefined") { //hide the validation summaries  
        for (var sums = 0; sums < window.Page_ValidationSummaries.length; sums++) {
            var summary = window.Page_ValidationSummaries[sums];
            summary.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    // remove the error class that I set in the callout server control
    $("input[type='text']").removeClass("wpcf7-not-valid");
    $("select").removeClass("wpcf7-not-valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to reset the validators.

```
function ResetValidators() {
    document.forms[0].reset();   

    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        Page_Validators[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in this scenario because of the validator callout